# The element 'Send' in namespace '*' has invalid child element 'Add_Records' in namespace '*'. Test Map failure for map file

Tags: xml, xsd, biztalk, biztalk-mapper

I have the following input file:

```
H|3      |20110607235508
V|M065      |3077999   |NH|PAS|20110608|213400|M| |   
V|M006      |EUR8944   |NY|PAS|20110608|213547|M| |   
V|M057      |UNV39S    |NJ|PAS|20110608|213908|M| |  
T|3      |20110607235508
```

And I have this schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns="http://BizTalkNyCase.Schemas.CaseFileSchema" xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" targetNamespace="http://BizTalkNyCase.Schemas.CaseFileSchema" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <schemaEditorExtension:schemaInfo namespaceAlias="b" extensionClass="Microsoft.BizTalk.FlatFileExtension.FlatFileExtension" standardName="Flat File" xmlns:schemaEditorExtension="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003/SchemaEditorExtensions" /> 
  <b:schemaInfo standard="Flat File" codepage="65001" default_pad_char="" pad_char_type="char" count_positions_by_byte="false" parser_optimization="speed" lookahead_depth="3" suppress_empty_nodes="false" generate_empty_nodes="true" allow_early_termination="false" early_terminate_optional_fields="false" allow_message_breakup_of_infix_root="false" compile_parse_tables="false" root_reference="CaseFileSchema" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="CaseFileSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="hex" child_delimiter="0xD 0xA" child_order="infix" sequence_number="1" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="CaseHeader" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element minOccurs="3" maxOccurs="3" name="CaseRecords">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:recordInfo structure="delimited" child_delimiter_type="char" child_delimiter="|" child_order="infix" sequence_number="2" preserve_delimiter_for_empty_data="true" suppress_trailing_delimiters="false" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <groupInfo sequence_number="0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Vehicle" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="1" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Officer_Id" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="2" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Vehicle_Tag" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="State" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="4" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Vehicle_Type" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="5" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TowDate" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="6" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TowTime" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="7" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TowType" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="8" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="TowIndicator" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="9" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Precinct" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="10" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="CaseTrailer" type="xs:string">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <b:fieldInfo justification="left" sequence_number="3" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

and this is the output schema

```
<xs:schema xmlns:b="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" attributeFormDefault="unqualified" elementFormDefault="qualified" targetNamespace="http://SqlAdapterCase" version="1.0" xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
  <xs:annotation>
  <xs:appinfo>
  <msbtssql:sqlScript value="exec [Add_Records] @OfficerId=" ", @Precinct=" ", @State=" ", @TowDate=" ", @TowIndicator=" ", @TowTime=" ", @TowType=" ", @Vehicle=" ", @VehicleTag=" ", @VehicleType=" "" xmlns:msbtssql="http://schemas.microsoft.com/BizTalk/2003" /> 
  </xs:appinfo>
  </xs:annotation>
  <xs:element name="Send">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Add_Records">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:attribute name="OfficerId" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="Precinct" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="State" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="TowDate" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="TowIndicator" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="TowTime" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="TowType" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="Vehicle" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="VehicleTag" type="xs:string" /> 
  <xs:attribute name="VehicleType" type="xs:string" /> 
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  <xs:element name="Recive">
  <xs:complexType>
  <xs:sequence>
  <xs:element name="Success" type="xs:anyType" /> 
  </xs:sequence>
  </xs:complexType>
  </xs:element>
  </xs:schema>
```

However when I test the map I get this error

> as
>   input to the map. C:\Users\Administrator\Desktop\error.xml: error
>   btm1046: Output validation error: The element 'Send' in namespace
>   'http://SqlAdapterCase' has invalid child element 'Add_Records' in
>   namespace 'http://SqlAdapterCase'. Test Map failure for map file

Comment: Where are details of your map and the output of your map?  It is the output that is failing validation, not the input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It'd be important to see your map and/or the output message to fully answer this question, but looking at your output schema, all values are required (`minOccurs` is not specified, which means it's defaulted to 1).

You have a few options:

1. If some nodes really aren't required and you want your schema to be consistent with that, update your schema so that attributes/elements that are not required have a `minOccurs="0"` on them.
2. Update your map so that it provides valid output to all required nodes/attributes (currently, all of them).  Even an empty string (or setting the node `Value` property to `<Empty>` will work).
3. Turn off validation on the mapper.  I generally do this - many times, developers don't bother to set `minOccurs="0"`, and the BizTalk runtime won't do the validation checking unless you specifically use the validating pipeline component (or some other custom validating component).  Map unit testing is usually more concerned with other things rather than whether all schema rules are being followed By default, these properties are set to **True** - change that to false.  You can always change it back later if you want to validate again.

[image: Map properties]